# If $g \circ f$ is surjective, what can you say about the surjectivity of $f$ and $g$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Given $f : A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$, if $g \circ f$ is surjective, what can you say about the surjectivity of $f$ and $g$?

*My Attempted Proof*

Suppose $g \circ f$ is surjetive  and assume either $f$ or $g$ not surjective.

Then $g(f(A)) \subset C$, and there exists  $c \in C$, such that $c \neq g(f(a))$ for any $a \in A$, contradicting our assumption.

Thus $g \circ f$ is surjective if and only if both $f$ and $g$ are surjective. $\square$

---

Is my proof correct? If so how rigorous is it?

Comment: I don't see why there should exist such a $c$. Besides, your assertion is false: you can only deduce $g$ is surjective. This is proved by contrapositive.

Answer (score 1):

g is surjective, cause  g(B) is overset of the g(f(A)) => g(B) = C

f may be not surjective.

Example:

A = B = C = R

f(x) = arctan(x)

g(x) = tan(x)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is mistaken. In fact, it isn't even a proof, it only superficially resembles one. Given that $g \circ f$ is surjective, then $(g \circ f) (A) = C$, so there exist no $c$ as you claim.

Comment: How so? I've assumed that $g \circ f$ is surjective and attempted to use my assumption to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $g \circ f$ is surjective, then (as your proof shows) $g$ is also surjective.

You cannot say anything about $f$. $f(A)$ could be all of $B$ or just enough of $B$ to feed into $g$ to hit all of $C$.

As an example: $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{1,2,3\}$, $C=\{1,2\}$. $f(1)=f(2)=1$ and $f(3)=2$. $g(1)=1$ and $g(2)=2$. Then $g \circ f$ is onto, $g$ is onto, but $f$ is not.

The converse doesn't work either, just because $g$ is surjective, you cannot conclude that $g \circ f$ is.

As an example: Same as above but let $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1$. Then $g$ is onto, but neither $f$ nor $g \circ f$ are.